# How can I monitor docker volume usage?

Tags: docker, shell-script

I'm planning to automate docker activities using python. However, I couldn't find any efficient command for monitoring docker volume. So now I wish to use shell commands for that and later it can be converted using subprocess in python.

My requirement is when I give a volume name then I need the used space, free space, and total space of that volume for finding the storage threshold of the same.

I tried using the `docker system df -v` But it showing all details.

For example, I give the volume name as my_volume then I need storage details of the same only. Hope everyone understood my requirement and excepting a helping hand from someone.

Comment: Hi. Do you mean attached volumes? Are you want to monitor container's native block device provided with `OverlayFS`?

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend a temporary container for this. It will work on just about any version of docker, and supports named volumes with non-default settings, e.g. that store data on remote systems (e.g. NFS) or modify the bind mound settings to use another folder.

A simple example is:

```
$ docker container run --rm -v "${volume_name}:/volume" -w /volume busybox df -P .
Filesystem           1024-blocks    Used Available Capacity Mounted on
/dev/..........              898086280 350169736 502226484  41% /volume
```

You can parse that output or reformat with the `df` command as appropriate for your use case. The busybox version of `df` will have fewer options than you may be used to:

```
$ df --help
BusyBox v1.31.1 (2019-12-23 19:20:27 UTC) multi-call binary.

Usage: df [-PkmhTai] [-B SIZE] [FILESYSTEM]...

Print filesystem usage statistics

        -P      POSIX output format
        -k      1024-byte blocks (default)
        -m      1M-byte blocks
        -h      Human readable (e.g. 1K 243M 2G)
        -T      Print filesystem type
        -a      Show all filesystems
        -i      Inodes
        -B SIZE Blocksize
```

Comment: Can you please explain this command `docker container run --rm -v "${volume_name}:/volume" -w /volume busybox df -P`

Comment: @EdwardArrow the command runs a container based on the busybox image with the volume mounted. It then runs the `df` command in that volume directory. And when the `df` command completes the container exits and the `--rm` automatically deletes the container. See `docker container run --help` for more details on the options.